# Anonymous Inner Classes Inside Methods

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

Please have a look at following code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main{
     public static <T> List<T> modifiedList(final List<T> list){
         return new ArrayList<T>(){
            @Override
             public boolean add(T element){
                 super.add(element);
                 return list.add(element);
             }
         };
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<String> originalList=new ArrayList<String>();
         List<String> duplicateList=modifiedList(originalList);
         originalList.add("1");
         originalList.add("2");
         originalList.add("3");
         System.out.println(originalList+" "+duplicateList);
         duplicateList.add("4");
         duplicateList.add("5");
         duplicateList.add("6");
         System.out.println(originalList+" "+duplicateList);
     }
```

In the above code, the instance of an anonymous inner class declared in the method modifiedList() is able to access the parameter passed to that method. AFAIK Java creates a separate bytecode file for inner classes.

Can anyone explain how these local variable bindings are handled by Java at the bytecode level? I mean, how exactly does Java keep track of the reference to the object passed as a parameter to that method?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*[Sorry for my poor English! If you understand my question, please edit this post and remove the grammatical errors. Thanks!]*

Comment: Your English is actually quite good. I only made a few small grammatical changes. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially the code is rewritten by the complier as (note I didn't try to compile it..., might have errors):

```
class Main$1<T>
    extends ArrayList<T>
{
    private final List<T> list;

    Main$1(final List<T> a)
    {
        list = a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T element)
    {
        super.add(element);
        return list.add(element);
    }
}
```

and

```
class Main{
     public static <T> List<T> modifiedList(final List<T> list)
     {
         return new Main$1<T>(list);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         List<String> originalList=new ArrayList<String>();
         List<String> duplicateList=modifiedList(originalList);
         originalList.add("1");
         originalList.add("2");
         originalList.add("3");
         System.out.println(originalList+" "+duplicateList);
         duplicateList.add("4");
         duplicateList.add("5");
         duplicateList.add("6");
         System.out.println(originalList+" "+duplicateList);
     }
```

Comment: That's why the compiler needs it declared final. For assuring that the value never changes, so the method inside the inner class can access the copied-never-changed value and know that's the correct semantics. If it were not final it shouldn't know if the value changed between inner object creation and inner object method invocation.

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main{
    public static <T> List<T> modifiedList(final List<T> list){
         return new ArrayList<T>(){

             private List<T> originalList=list;

             @Override
             public boolean add(T element){
                 super.add(element);
                 return originalList.add(element);
             }
         };
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<String> originalList=new ArrayList<String>();
         List<String> duplicateList=modifiedList(originalList);
         originalList.add("1");
         originalList.add("2");
         originalList.add("3");
         System.out.println(originalList+" "+duplicateList);
         duplicateList.add("4");
         duplicateList.add("5");
         duplicateList.add("6");
         System.out.println(originalList+" "+duplicateList);       
     }
 }
```

Java allows such a strange thing just in order to make things easier for programmers.
Both the codes are semantically same and boil down to the identical bytecode.