# Anonymous Listener inside for loop

Tags: java, mouselistener

This may be a stupid question but in my code when **mouseClicked** is performed on a panel will the **item** from the loop condition be the same as the item parameter of **ItemDialog**?

```
for (Item item: itemsList) {
        JPanel panel = new ItemPanel(item);
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                new ItemDialog(item);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
});
```

Comment: Yes. There is no other `item` in your `for-each` loop, so the reference is straightforward.
Debug the code in your IDE, what do you see?

Comment: To downvoters: this isn't a stupid question.  It's a good question about the confusing scoping of anonymous inner-classes, and how they guarantee the value will still be the same in the future. Plus loop-scoped variables. Plus Java-8 automatically making the variables `final`.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. There are dozens of questions where false assumption has let to bugs, e.g. stackoverflow.com/questions/8327781/ (EDIT: Or for short: I agree to Mr. Spoon)

Comment: Maybe tag it with java version  then, if there's difference between 7 & 8 in this field? I'd say it wouldn't compile in the first place. Thanks @MrSpoon for pointing difference I wasn't aware of .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes is the simple answer.

But, like I said in my comment, there's a lot going on here!

Anonymous inner-classes are confusing: a similar headache to closures in Javascript.

They can access variables that are defined outside of themselves.  They can *still* access those same variable references at arbitrary points in the future, even when the variable would otherwise be out of scope.  The rule that makes this possible is that those variables have to be declared as `final`.

This post explains the mechanics better than I can: [How does java implement inner class closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804923/how-does-java-implement-inner-class-closures)

An aside: Since Java 8, the compiler *automatically* makes each of your `Item item` variables `final` because it spots they are being used in your anonymous inner-class. So they effectively become:

```
for (final Item item: itemsList) {
```