# Java - final variable requirement in OnClickListener

Tags: java

I have a program which has a text box that the user can edit. When the user presses a button a Dialog box is created, displaying the user's text and a confirm 'yes/no' option.

```
public void setIP(View v){
    //get the text inside the editor
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIP);
    final String IP = et.getText().toString();

    //create dialog 
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Set I.P. to : " + IP + " ?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    host = IP;
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

This code works fine, but my first version would not compile. My IDE complained that I should make the string `IP` `final`, when It was not.

This got me thinking. What does `final` add in this case? What if, for example, I chose to keep a reference to the Dialog, and show it from another method. This means the method above will have returned. So how can the variable `IP` linger on?

Does the final keyword just ensure the value isn't changed elsewhere, allowing the onClickListener to store the value of `IP`, knowing it will still be true? is the scope of `IP` increased?

Comment: Please see: [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When and why does an EventHandler require objects to be final?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809131/when-and-why-does-an-eventhandler-require-objects-to-be-final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the final keyword just ensure the value isn't changed elsewhere, allowing the onClickListener to store the value of `IP`, knowing it will still be true? is the scope of `IP` increased?

In a sense, yes (though this is really the "extent" rather than the "scope": the "scope" is still just the program text between the declaration of `IP` and the `}` at the end of the function).

Implementation-wise, essentially what is happening is that the `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... }` has an implicit field named `IP` that is automatically initialized during the object's construction. The `final` modifier serves to protect the abstraction of there being a single `IP` variable, by ensuring that the local variable `IP` and the implicit field `IP` continue to refer to the same `String` instance.

Comment: Then what about primitive types? Why do they have to be final?

Comment: @SahandMozaffari I think ruakh's explanation is equally applicable to primitives.

Comment: @SahandMozaffari: It's the exact same thing; just change the last bit to "by ensuring that the local variable `IP` and the implicit field `IP` continue to have the same value".