# Android: Unable to dismiss custom dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-gridview

I have a custom dialog with gridview in it.
The dialog pops up when I click a textview(runs). There is a gridview in the dialog.
My objective is to change value of runs textview on selecting the value from gridview and dismiss the dialog

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch (id) {
    case CATEGORY_ID:

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        // Context mContext = this;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_cell,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

        GridView gridview = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.text_gridview, R.id.run_cell, numbers);

        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setView(layout);
        dialog = builder.create();
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                runs.setText(String.valueOf(position));
       **dialog.cancel() or dialog.dismiss are giving me this error: 'Cannot refer to a non-final variable result inside an inner class defined in a different method'**
            }
        });
        break;

    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Dialog dialog = null;
```

Do

```
final Dialog dialog;
```

For a better explanation of this, check [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857394/java-final-variable-requirement-in-onclicklistener).

**Edit**

I didn't see the rest of the problem.  Seeing as you have a `switch` statement, you can just use `default` to set the value as follows:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    final Dialog dialog;
    switch (id) {
        case CATEGORY_ID: 
           //your code
           break;
        default:
           dialog = null;
           break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: after your suggested change I get this error       **"The local variable dialog may not have been initialized"** on line **return dialog;**

Comment: @Andrew Schuster don't you get a Compilation Error in `dialog = null`? I mean an Error like `The final local variable dialog cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing Type`

Comment: @Gödel77, I do not get such an error.  Under what context do you receive that?  Also, what's your IDE for Android?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster in a normal custom Method in which I create a Dialog as final like you and then in onClick of positive/negative Button I wanted to ensure that the dialog closes , you know `dialog.dismiss()` + `dialog=null`. Regards