# How to visualize nested lambda syntax?

Tags: multithreading, lambda, java-8

For the below code,

```
public class X{
    ...
    static class Y implements Runnable{
     .....
         List<Thread> makeWorkerThreads(Function<String, Void> task) {
             List<Thread> workerThreads  =  new ArrayList<>();
             mInputList.forEach(input -> workerThreads.add
                            (new Thread( 
                                    () -> task.apply(input)
                                    )));
             return workerThreads;
         }
         ....
    } // Y
    ....
} // X
```

where `task` is

```
private Void processInput(String input) {
        ...
}
```

---

Could not understand below syntax,

```
mInputList.forEach(input -> workerThreads.add
                            (new Thread(
                                        () -> task.apply(input)
                                       )
                            )
                    );
```

---

How `task.apply(input)` resolve name `input` in overridden `run()` method? 
Could not visualize run() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mInputList.forEach()` accepts a `Consumer<? super String> action` argument, where `String` is the element type of your `mInputList` `List`.

Therefore you can look at the outer lambda expression as an anonymous class instance that implements the `Consumer` interface, and therefore has a `void accept(String t);` method.

Now, `forEach` applies that `accept` method for each element of your `mInputList`.

The implementation of the `accept` method in your code looks like this:

```
void accept (String input) {
    workerThreads.add (new Thread(() -> task.apply(input)));
}
```

Now you can see where `input` comes from.

The inner lambda expression `() -> task.apply(input)` implements the `Runnable` interface. i.e. it implements a method that takes no argument (hence the `()` part) and returns nothing (in this case `task.apply(input)` does return a value, but it is ignored).

Comment: Is the  anonymous class that implements `Runnable` interface, declared within method `accept`()? Because `input` is visible within the scope of  `accept`() method

Comment: @overexchange yes. instead of `new Thread(() -> task.apply(input))`, you can write `new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {task.apply(input);}})`

Comment: OK. Does anonymous inner class `new Runnable(){override run() }` further get declared as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1950822/3317808)? If yes, what will be the scope of that class(`class something$ implements Runnable{}`) ?

Comment: @overexchange: no, the anonymous classes generated for lambda expressions have nothing to do with anonymous inner classes. It’s best to consider their existence an unimportant implementation detail. They have no scope, as scope is a source code thing and there is no inner class in your source code.